# Persistent https connection on nodeMCU

Tags: c++, https, arduino, nodemcu

I am trying to build a persistent connection between my nodeMCU and a remote server since I will be using that to post to a remote server every 2 seconds. The cost of reconnecting is roughly 400ms which is too much in my case.

I once run connect snippet inside the setup function

```
 int r=0; 
 while((!httpsClient.connect(host, httpsPort)) && (r < 30))
{
 delay(100);
 Serial.print(".");
 r++;
}
Serial.println("");
if(r==30) {
 Serial.println("Connection failed");
}
else {
 Serial.println("Connected to web");
}
```

Then inside the while loop, I run https post method every 2 seconds or so.

```
httpsClient.print(String("POST ") + "/post HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
           "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
           "Content-Type: application/json"+ "\r\n" +
           "Content-Length: "+String(measureJson(doc)+2) + "\r\n\r\n" );
serializeJson(doc, JSONmessageBuffer);
httpsClient.print(JSONmessageBuffer);
httpsClient.print("\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");
```

But sadly I can send the package just once and the connection is closed automatically. Can you point me in the direction of how persistent HTTPS connections should be made?

Comment: Not sure what library you are using, but you should connect once,see this example: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101SSLClient, and also don't use Delay, see https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay

Comment: hey Haoun , I am using WiFiClientSecure.h .

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you have

```cpp
httpsClient.print("\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");
```

in the wrong place. It should be included in the request headers - not after the body of the request. By the time you send the `Connection: keep-alive` line, you have already sent data of a length specified in your `Content-Length:` header. The server treats it as a new HTTP request - albeit a malformed one - so closes the TCP connection.

You may be able inspect the HTTP server logs to verify this. If your server is Apache, for example, you might see a line which includes

> "Connection: Keep-alive" 400

I.e., the server has interpreted your `Connection: keep-alive` line as a separate request. The 400 indicates a `Bad request`.

In fact ... You may be able to remove the `Connection: keep-alive` entirely - as connections are persistent by default in HTTP 1.1.